# Write to XCode build transcript

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

Is there any way to write to the XCode build transcript? What i want to do, is throw a warning if a device is not attached to the computer instead of an assertion failure in my unit test cases (some cases rely on an attached ipod).

I thought of something like the standard compiler warnings (only with custom message).

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In shell build phases you can write to stderr using the following format:

`<filename>:<linenumber>: error | warn | note : <message>\n`

It's the same format gcc uses to show errors. The filename:linenumber part can be omitted. Depending on the mode (error, warn, note), Xcode will show your message with a red or yellow badge.

If you include an absolute file path and a line number (if the error occurred in a file), double clicking the error in the build log lets Xcode open the file and jumps to the line, even if it is not part of the project. Very handy.

Comment: I've made myself a macro for this, but somehow it doesn't seem to show up in the buildlog, although it prints exactly the same string as gcc :(
    #define STWarning(msg) fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: warning: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, msg)

Comment: the file and line underscores got lost somehow, assume they're there.

Comment: oh sorry... you ment BUILD PHASES. mhm is there some method that would work directly from code? (i guess not)

Comment: eaigner: You can't write to the build log after the build has finished.

Comment: Thought so. But how are unit tests executed? Their runs/assertions appear in the build transcript too.

Comment: They are run from a shell script build phase. As such, output from test cases should appear in the build log if properly formatted.